# android with java threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to create a simple thread that started from a Button but something went wrong.
Here is the code:

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            SendInfo si = new SendInfo();
            si.start();
            error.setText(si.getError());

        }
    });
```

And here is the the thread code:

```
package com.example.android.location;

public class SendInfo extends Thread
{
    private String error;

    public void run()
    {
        this.error = "working";
    }
    public String getError(){
        return this.error;
    }   
}
```

For some reason the error instance in the first code block stays empty.

Comment: I recommend you to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). With `AsynCtask` you can do UI operations when your thread has finished.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace with us?

Comment: When I did my first Android app, I used java threads because it was familiar. But then I decided to learn AsyncTask, and let me tell you it is FAR easier. Give it a shot, it's not near as bad as it first looks

Comment: for some reason ? you kinda started a thread ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race.

After the `start()` call either:

1) your code continues and `getError` returns null and AFTER that the thread runs.

or

2) the thread runs AND finishes and `getError`will return "working".

In your case 1) is happening.

Update: actually in theory during option 2 you might not get "working" anyway as the return value. This is due to memory/thread visibility. Synchronizing access to the error variable or in this case just declaring that field volatile fixes that (but not your original problem).

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that the thread started after this line

`si.start();`

so you can't just get `error` in hope that it's set as expected. Your thread didn't by the looks of it.

Also, it would be wise to synchronize on the method, to prevent nasty reordering of instructions.

One solution to this problem as a whole, is to create a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) on main thread and send a message to it once your thread completes execution.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use ASyncTask than Thread.